# update_attribute with error undefined method `update_attribute' for #<Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters, update-attribute

The specific code below from the book using Rails 4
I believed in rails 5 required strong parameters that may cause error in Rails 5.
Please anyone could share me. How to apply permit and require for the following code)

From model user.rb

```
def remember
    remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
end
```

error (in rails 5)

```
NoMethodError in SessionsController#create
undefined method `update_attribute' for #<Class
```

Here what I did.

```
def remember
    remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(params:[remember_token]))
end
```

error:

```
NoMethodError in SessionsController#create
undefined method `update_attribute' for #<Class:0x007fd23b30a790> Did you mean? _default_attributes
```

Tobe clear: those method called from sessionshelper.erb

```
module SessionsHelper

  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # Remembers a user in a persistent session.
  def remember(user)
    User.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end


    # Returns the user corresponding to the remember token cookie.
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end


  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

# Forgets a persistent session.
  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end
  # Logs out the current user.
  def log_out
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token, :remember_digest
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password   
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
class << self
  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  def remember
    remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end



  # Returns a random token.
  def new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end
end
  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(remember_token)
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  end
  # Forgets a user.
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

  def activate
    update_attribute(:activated,    true)
    update_attribute(:activated_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

end
```

sessionscontroller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      remember user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out
    redirect_to url_for(:controller => :sessions, :action => :new)  
  end
end
```

[image: Eooro]

Comment: Hi, with this error, I think it's not a problem with parameters. It's not finding the method `update_attribute`.

Comment: Can you show me your model class , Is it properly inherited from application record ?

Comment: Just a thought: according to the error (`undefined method 'update_attribute' for #<Class`), it seems like you're calling it from a class (aren't you defining remember with `self.remember`?), and not from a model instance.

Comment: I updated the caller in my edit

Comment: the issue is `User.remember` should be `user.remember` in helper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The issue is in the helper**, the line

You are calling the `remember` method with the `User` class, so it is showing `undefined method for class`. Instead call with `user object`

**`User.remember`**

should be,

**`user.remember`**

```
def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end
```

Comment: This won't make any difference , self in instance methods are optional

Comment: how did you call this method?, and you have `current_user`?

Comment: the issue is `User.remember` should be `user.remember` in helper

Comment: Updated my ans, please check

Comment: Hi Seavan. It's return error: NoMethodError in SessionsController#create
undefined method `remember' for #<User:0x007fd239631768> Did you mean? remember_token If I change User.remember to user.remember

Comment: you are storing `current_user` wrong. Please add full helper.

Comment: render `current_user` and check if `current_user` is presenmt

Comment: once remove `class << self` and try

Comment: Here what happened. Before SessionController call remember user 'current_user' still have data But in user.erb the current_user is nil.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133609/discussion-between-sravan-and-t-kul).

Answer (score 0):

i have a similar implementation,maybe this might help you

in `user.rb`

```
  def create_confimation_token
    generate_token(:confirmation_token)
    update_attribute(:expiration,Time.zone.now + 2.days)
    save!  
  end

  def generate_token(column)
      begin
        self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
      end 
  end
```

Comment: I tried then error: NoMethodError in SessionsController#create
undefined method `update_attribute' for #<Class:0x007fd2343b5638> Did you mean? _default_attributes

Comment: this is how i have implemented to save token in user.rb..@T.Kul

Comment: Thanks but let me work on the same solution then yours is another. Will update later

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling `update_attribute` on the `user`
try

```
current_user.update_attribute(a: b)
```

in your `SessionsController#create`

Comment: Hi Zhong I don't  understand. currently it called from sessionshelp now you want to change by call fro user ?

Comment: It already called from SessionsController by 'remember user' is it?

Answer (score 0):

update_attributes is an instance method not a class method, so first thing you need to call it on an instance of User class.

like:

```
 @user.update_attributes(:remember_digest, User.digest(params:[remember_token]))
```

Try this once.

Comment: Hi jyoti, it's NoMethodError in SessionsController#create
undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass

Comment: do you find anything in @user?

Answer (score 0):

u should call update_attributes for a user object.

helper.rb

```
  def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end
```

model.rb

```
  def remember
    remember_token = new_token
    self.update_attributes(:remember_digest, digest(remember_token))
  end
```

Comment: NoMethodError in SessionsController#create
undefined method `remember' for #<User:0x007fd23d0e0300> Did you mean? remember_token        As shown on printscreen attached the Question Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### It worked Now

What happened are the

1. class << self in user.rb

cause following method not working.

```
def remember
  remember_token = User.new_token
  update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
end
```

2. User.remember in SessionsHelper should be

   `user.remember`

Thanks everyone